# How to use ElementsAreArray matcher in EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
EXPECT_CALL(*backendHttpResponseStatusLogger, LogValue(0, ElementsAreArray({ "ip1:p1", "pool1", "setting1", "1xx" }))).Times(1);
```

Gives me compilation error as below. What would be the right way to use it.
signature of function LogValue is `void(int64_t, const string[])`

```
 /appgwtlib/googletest/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In instantiation of 'class testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>':
    /appgwtlib/googletest/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3532:23:   required from 'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<T>::operator testing::Matcher<T>() const [with Container = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; T = const char*]'
    NginxMetricHandlerTests.cpp:85:3:   required from here
    /appgwtlib/googletest/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3114:45: error: 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>::StlContainer {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' is not a class, struct, or union type
       typedef typename StlContainer::value_type Element;
                                                 ^
    /appgwtlib/googletest/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3248:43: error: 'testing::internal::StlContainerView<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>::type {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' is not a class, struct, or union type
       ::std::vector<Matcher<const Element&> > matchers_;
```

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think it's possible to do it this using `ElementsAreArray` (or any other cointainer matcher)**

I'm not 100% if I read the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#container-matchers) correctly, but it seems C-style array must be either passed by reference or together with it's size for the matchers to work.

Notice this error:

```
error: 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>::StlContainer {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Member of the GMock internal class is called `StlContainer`, but it's `std::string*` instead.

It's not going to work, unless you pass the number of elements in the array (which you probably should do anyway when you're dealing with C-style arrays).

---

Instead you can write your own matcher, which will be unsafely (without knowing the real size of the array) comparing the elements:

```
MATCHER_P(CStyleArrayEqual, arrayToCompare, "")
{
    int i = 0;
    for(const auto& elem: arrayToCompare)
    {
        //very, VERY unsafe! You don't know the length of arg!
        //std::initializer_list doesn't have operator[], have to resort to other methods
        if(arg[i] != elem)
            return false;
        ++i;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this requires passing a valid object (*braced-init-lists* don't work with templates):

```
EXPECT_CALL(*backendHttpResponseStatusLogger, LogValue(0, CStyleArrayEqual(std::vector<std::string>{"1", "2"})));
```

To avoid explicitly naming the type, you can predeclare the variable:

```
auto arrayToMatch {"1", "2"}; //type is std::initializer_list<std::string>
EXPECT_CALL(*backendHttpResponseStatusLogger, LogValue(0, CStyleArrayEqual(arrayToMatch)));
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/KZ4LfX)